# RegEx for checking if number is less or greater than

Tags: regex, for-loop

I need expression to check if number 7 is less than 30 and greater than 1. This is an example. Can anybody provide expression and an explanation?

Comment: Regex is probably not the best way to approach this...

Comment: This is an example of much complex problem. I have other solution but i need to find one with regex.

Comment: Please describe the complex problem then - do the ranges change? Why regex?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

```
^([2-9]|[1-2][0-9])$
```

The expression above will match, if:

- the given string is one character long and that character is a number ranging from 2 to 9
- the given string is two characters long, first character is 1 or 2 and the second character ranges from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex, but if you want to, here you go:

```
^(?:[2-9]|[1-2][0-9])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ezj-KOomNmS1k31w)

---

**Explanation:**

This anchors to the beginning/end of the string (so we don't match `7` in the number `175`) and then all of the logic happens in the non-capturing group.  Either match the numbers `[2-9 ]` (greater than 1) *OR* match `[1-2]` followed by any digit `[0-9]` (range from 10-29). Notice that I used `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because it fits better for readability and `\d` technically will match other numeric characters (Arabic, etc).

---

Side note, if you want to allow leading 0's (`1 < 007 == 7 < 30`), you can allow for 0+ 0's after the start of the string:

```
^0*(?:[2-9]|[1-2][0-9])$
```