# Regular Expression Intervals: Less or equal

Tags: regex

Is there a more efficient way to check integers in the intervall from 0 to 250?

**Regular Expression:**

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$
```

Or what about an intervall from 0 to 20'000, 0 to 100'000, etc.?

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is easier way of doing that using regex.

Comment: No more efficient way to do it (other than slightly optimizing it like @TimPietzcker did), and the expression will get exponentially larger as you go.  [Check an answer of mine on a similar question..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637637/regex-for-checking-if-number-is-less-or-greater-than/23637810#23637810)

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with a regex like `/^\d+$/`, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Comment: Okay, damn. The reason, I wanted to use reg ex is, that I want to prevent user inputs (in C#/ WPF) of letters and special characters. Any user should only be allowed to enter integers in the range from 0 to 250, resp. 0 to 20000...

Comment: By the way I use in WPF textboxes, that allow by default strings, that should be validated...

Answer (score 1):

Not really; you can shorten it a tiny bit:

```
^([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$
```

But regexes are not good for number ranges, especially arbitrary ranges.